# Why do I can alway get label in getAsObject() in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I do not why although I verify everything which is right. Anyone know?
I tried to debug:
- getAsString() return ID (that's right)
- when I submitted - getAsObject() always throw exception because the label values was always passed instead of ID values.
My code as below:

**my xhtml file:**

```
<div class="ui-grid-row" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2 pdt4">
            <p:outputLabel for="txtApprovalScheduler"
                           value="#{lang['workforce.category.parttimeManagement.approved.scheduler']}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{parttimeController.selectedAgentDTO}"
                             id="txtApprovalScheduler"
                             filterMatchMode="contains" editable="true"
                             style="width: 86%;"
                             required="true"
                             requiredMessage="#{lang['workforce.category.parttimeManagement.approved.scheduler.missing']}">
                <f:converter converterId="agentConverter"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{lang['wf.common.choose']}"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{parttimeController.agentDTOs}" var="agentItem1"
                               itemLabel="#{agentItem1.userName}"
                               itemValue="#{agentItem1}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2 pdt4">
            <p:outputLabel for="txtApprovalRegister"
                           value="#{lang['workforce.category.parttimeManagement.approved.register']}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{parttimeController.selectedAgentDTOForRegister}"
                             id="txtApprovalRegister" editable="true"
                             filterMatchMode="contains" style="width: 86%; font-size: 12px !important;"
                             required="true"
                             requiredMessage="#{lang['workforce.category.parttimeManagement.approved.register.missing']}">
                <f:converter converterId="agentConverter"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{lang['wf.common.choose']}"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{parttimeController.agentDTOs}" var="item1"
                               itemLabel="#{item1.userName}"
                               itemValue="#{item1}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My Converter:**

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = AgentDTO.class,value = "agentConverter")
public class AgentConverter implements Converter {

    public static List<AgentDTO> listAgentDTOs;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String agentId) {
        if (agentId.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                Long number = Long.parseLong(agentId);
                for (AgentDTO a : listAgentDTOs) {
                    if (a.getAgentId() == number) {
                        return a;
                    }
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid data"));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("") || "-1".equals(value)) {
            return "";
        } else {
            String result = String.valueOf(((AgentDTO) value).getAgentId());
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**My bean:**

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
@ManagedBean(name = "parttimeController")
public class ParttimeController extends BaseController implements Serializable {
private AgentDTO selectedAgentDTO;
private AgentDTO selectedAgentDTOForRegister;
private List<AgentDTO> agentDTOs;
.... getter/setter and initiallize AgentCenvert.listAgentDTOs
```

**My class:**

```
public class AgentDTO{
    private Long agentId;
private String userName;
....getter/setter
}
```

Comment: So it works if you use a plain jsf `h:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: @Kukeltje: I have to use p:selectOneMenu for some reason related to synchronization

Comment: That was not my question. Your title suggests it **only** fails with PrimeFaces. If you try with the plain jsf version, you'll notice the issue is not related to PrimeFaces (off-topic; jsf **and** spring annotations on the same bean is wrong)

Comment: Could you try removing _value = "agentConverter"_ and also remove the f:converter's. Also do you have a h:form?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason - I only remove **editable** attribute in **selectOneMenu**. So getAsObject() will pass a value instead of a label